# Media-query Aspect ratio

Tags: css, media-queries, aspect-ratio

I would like to change the background-color of `h1` element when the browser ratio is 4:3. I've tried using `aspect-ratio` in my media query, but for some reason it doesn't work. How can I fix this issue?

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/s4ek1389/pen/MxWqrg

HTML:

```
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

CSS:

```
  h1 {
      background-color: red;
    }

    @media screen and (aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
      h1 {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `aspect-ratio` try using `max-aspect-ratio`.

```css
h1 {
  background-color: red;
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
  h1 {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```